# Indenting nested namespaces on the same line to just one level

Tags: c++, emacs, namespaces, indentation

In emacs 21:

```
namespace Abc { namespace Def { 
    class X;
    namespace Ghi {
        class Y;
    }
} }
```

But now in emacs 22.2.1:

```
namespace Abc { namespace Def {
        class X;
        namespace Ghi {
            class Y;
        }
    } }
```

How do I get the old behaviour back? Note that I don't want a fixed column for indentation, I want it to indent *one* level regardless of how many 'namespace {' the line contains.

Comment: Apologies as this is not directly relevant to the question, but is your project so large and maintained by so many independent developers that you need nested namespaces? It looks as though namespaces are being used here more for organizational purposes than to avoid name conflicts, but I'd recommend against doing that as it can cause more headaches in the long run (ex: ADL problems).

Comment: What is wrong with nested namespaces?

Answer (score 3):

I actually found the answer myself, in a moment of clear thinking:

```
(defun followed-by (cases)
  (cond ((null cases) nil)
        ((assq (car cases) 
               (cdr (memq c-syntactic-element c-syntactic-context))) t)
        (t (followed-by (cdr cases)))))


(c-add-style  "foo"      
              `( ...
        (c-offsets-alist
         ( ... )
         (innamespace
          . (lambda (x) 
          (if (followed-by 
               '(innamespace namespace-close)) 0 '+))))))
```

The '...' symbolizes other personalizations of course.